# Java recursion Issue with the flood fill algorithm

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to write a program to locate and count all connected regions in a grid. A connected region consists of a set of marked cells (value 1) such that each cell in the region can be reached by moving up, down, left or right from another marked cell in the region, cells on a diagonal line are not considered connected. 
So, it would take an input of:

```
10 20  
0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0  
0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1  
0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1  
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0  
1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0  
1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0  
0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0  
0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0  
0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0  
1   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0
```

And outputs:

```
0   1   1   0   0   0   2   0   3   3   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   5   0  
0   1   1   1   0   2   2   0   0   3   0   0   4   4   4   0   0   0   5   5  
0   0   1   0   0   0   2   2   0   3   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   5   5   5  
6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   3   0   0   7   0   0   0   5   5   5   0  
6   6   0   6   0   0   0   3   3   3   0   0   0   8   8   0   5   5   0   0  
6   6   6   6   0   0   0   0   0   0   9   0   8   8   8   0   0   0   0   0  
0   6   6   6   0   0   0   9   9   9   9   0   0   8   8   0   8   0   0   0  
0   6   6   6   6   6   0   0   9   9   9   0   0   0   8   8   8   8   8   0  
0   0   0   6   6   0   0   0   0   9   0   0   0   8   8   0   0   8   8   0  
10  0   6   6   6   6   6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8   8   0   8   0   0
```

Right now, when I run the code, I get:

```
0   2   2   0   0   0   2   0   2   2   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   2   0
0   3   3   3   0   3   3   0   0   3   0   0   3   3   3   0   0   0   3   3
0   0   4   0   0   0   4   4   0   4   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   4   4   4
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   5   0   0   5   0   0   0   5   5   5   0
6   6   0   6   0   0   0   6   6   6   0   0   0   6   6   0   6   6   0   0
7   7   7   7   0   0   0   0   0   0   7   0   7   7   7   0   0   0   0   0
0   8   8   8   0   0   0   8   8   8   8   0   0   8   8   0   8   0   0   0
0   9   9   9   9   9   0   0   9   9   9   0   0   0   9   9   9   9   9   0
0   0   0   10  10  0   0   0   0   10  0   0   0   10  10  0   0   10  10  0
11  0   11  11  11  11  11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11  11  0   11  0   0
```

Here is my code:

```
package project2;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project2 {


    private static int height;
    private static int length;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String inputFile;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter input file name: ");
        inputFile = "test_case_proj2.txt";

        try {
            Integer grid[][] = loadGrid(inputFile);

            System.out.println("Before flood fill");
            printGrid(grid);

            findGroups(grid, 0, 0, 2, height, length);

            System.out.println("After flood fill");
            printGrid(grid);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void findGroups(Integer[][] array, int column, int row,
            int counter, int height, int length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {

                if (row < 0 || row >= length || column < 0 || column >= height) {
                } else {
                    if (array[column][j] == 1) {
                        array[column][j] = counter;
                        findGroups(array, column, row + 1, counter, height, length);
                        findGroups(array, column, row - 1, counter, height, length);
                        findGroups(array, column - row, j, counter, height, length);
                        findGroups(array, column + row, j, counter, height, length);
                    }
                }     


            }
            counter++;
            column++;
            row++;
        }
    }

    public static Integer[][] loadGrid(String fileName) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream fin;

        fin = new FileInputStream(fileName);

        Scanner input = new Scanner(fin);

        height = input.nextInt();
        length = input.nextInt();

        Integer grid[][] = new Integer[height][length];

        for (int r = 0; r < height; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < length; c++) {
                grid[r][c] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
        fin.close();

        return (grid);
    }

    public static void printGrid(Integer[][] grid) {
        for (Integer[] grid1 : grid) {
            for (int c = 0; c < grid[0].length; c++) {
                System.out.printf("%3d", grid1[c]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Does someone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't cou increment the `counter` only when the `i,j`-th item is indeed land? So you need to move it inside the `if`-body I guess...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You put too much responsibilities into one method. You combine the floodfill algorithm with your island numbering algorithm.

I've created this [jdoodle](http://jdoodle.com/a/7U).

First of all you better create a single `fill` method, that does nothing more than filling islands with the value of a counter (I've made it static so you don't need to pass it through the algorithm, although this is arbitrary):

```
public static void fill(Integer[][] array, int column, int row, int height, int length) {
    if (row >= 0 && row < length && column >= 0 && column < height && array[column][row] == 1) {
        array[column][row] = counter;
        fill(array, column, row + 1, height, length);
        fill(array, column, row - 1, height, length);
        fill(array, column - 1, row, height, length);
        fill(array, column + 1, row, height, length);
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's a simple algorithm that uses recursion.

Secondly, you simply create a method that calls the `fill` algorithm on all the possible tiles. If you reach a point with a value of `1`, you know that this island has not been claimed by another king yet :D. Thus you fill it and claim it to the king with the `counter` id. Normally one uses a special array of boolean to prevent the `fill` algorithm to go into an infinite loop. You solved this smartly by starting to assign number from index `counter = 2`, of course once all island are claimed, you need to decrement the value.

```
public static void findGroups(Integer[][] array, int column, int row, int height, int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            if (array[i][j] == 1) {
                fill(array, i,j, height, length);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            if (array[i][j] > 1) {
                array[i][j]--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The rest of the algorithm remains the same (the algorithm now reads from `stdin`, but this is simply to make sure the jdoodle keeps working).

---

About your algorithm, it's quite hard to understand. For instance you use a fill and part of the calls use `column` and `row`, other parts use `j`. Next your counter is only updated for each row. This causes problems if two idlands start at the same row (as you can see with your output).

Comment: @CommuSoft, thank you for your answer, I made those changes and I am getting a StackOverflowError in the fill method. Any ideas? It could be a user error, as I am fairly new. Thanks again!

Comment: Did you perform a copy-paste or did you modify some parts? As you can see, the jdoodle doesn't result in a SO error. When using the `fill` algorithm, you **must** assign the value to the cell before calling the algorithm recursively.

Comment: @CommuSoft, copy-paste.

Comment: This is quite impossible, especially since the jdoodle succeeds to run the code without any trouble. Did you assign 2 as initial value to the counter?

Comment: @user3052882: You can download the file from the jdoodle (at "others" button). Then you can enter the values from stdin. If there are still problems you or you're IDE probably forgot to recompile it...